# ApexCharts.js Vue -> Flex and justify-between on legend

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, apex, apexcharts

I would like to achieve the effect as in the attached photo no. 2. How to stretch the dot, diagram name and value along the entire length and cover card with whole diagram

[image]

[image]

I put that code to main.css :

```
.donut .apexcharts-legend {
  @apply flex flex-col 
}
```

And here is my chartOptons :

```
const chartOptions = ref({
  chart: {
    type: "donut",
  },
  legend: {
    position: "bottom",
    horizontalAlign: 'right', 
    verticalAlign: 'right', 
    fontSize: '12px',
    formatter: function(label, opts) {
        return label + "   " + opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex]
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  title: {
    text: "Best selling products",
    align: "left",
    offsetX: -10,
    style: {
      fontSize: "20px",
    },
  },
  colors: ["#2466F5", "#F87171", "#FECD2F", "#10B981"],
  labels: [
    "V-neck T-shirt",
    "Oversize hoodie",
    "Premium Longsleeve",
    "Mug 400ml",
  ],
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      size: 400,
      donut: {
        labels: {
          show: true,
          total: {
            show: true,
            label: "Total",
            formatter: function (w) {
              const total = w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce((a, b) => {
                return a + b;
              }, 0);
              return total + " pcs";
            },

            fontSize: "14px",
            fontWeight: 400,
            color: "#5D789A",
          },
          value: {
            show: true,
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontWeight: 600,
            offsetY: -2,
            color: "#2F3A4B",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I tried to add justify-between in @apply but it doesn't work